# How to make the middle column of a table fill the remaining width and wrap its content if necessary

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple page as below which is used to specify a file by the user. Each row in the table has three 'td's. The first tdis a label, and last td is a button. The middle td is used to display the full path of the given file. And the middle td is expected to fill the remaining space and it should wrap its content if the file name is too long.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr style="width:100%;">
        <td style="width:auto;background:red;white-space:nowrap;">
            <span>License File</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:100%;background:blue;white-space:normal">
            <div style="display:block;">
                <span class="file_name"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:auto;background:gray;white-space:nowrap;">
            <input type="button" value="Install License File" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="width:100%;">
        <td style="width:auto;background:red;white-space:nowrap;">
            <span>Control File</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:100%;background:blue;white-space:normal">
            <div style="display:block;">
                <span class="file_name"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:auto;background:gray;white-space:nowrap;">
            <input type="button" value="Install Control File" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Lookup css display: flex, flex: auto and flex: none. I've not used it in tables but it may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Set const width for first and last column. Its short number and button so you can pick some width. Set `width: auto` for middle column and `width: 100%` for entire `table` as you already have. To be sure on any browser, you can add `min-width: 100%` to `table`, and also `max-width` with same value as `width` to first and last column.