# How can I get one dynamic width table column (with fixed widths for the other columns)

Tags: css, html-table

Please re-open this question, as the duplicate it was closed with does not solve the problem (but an answer in the comments does, and we can get it as a proper answer if this is re-opened).

I'm trying to make a simple table with four columns, where three of the four columns have a fixed width, and a middle column fills the remaining space.  This is not a new problem;  all of these SO posts address it:

- [How to make the middle column of a table fill the remaining width and wrap its content if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968323/how-to-make-the-middle-column-of-a-table-fill-the-remaining-width-and-wrap-its-c)
- [How to make last cell of a row in a table occupy all remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060933/how-to-make-last-cell-of-a-row-in-a-table-occupy-all-remaining-width)
- [CSS Table with one column taking remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044452/css-table-with-one-column-taking-remaining-space)
- [HTML table last td to take remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162482/html-table-last-td-to-take-remaining-width)
- [How to make a table cell stretch for the rest of the width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312597/how-to-make-a-table-cell-stretch-for-the-rest-of-the-width)

However, all of those posts have essentially the same answer: use `table-layout: fixed`, put a `max-width` style on the fixed-width columns, and use `width: auto` on the column with dynamic width ... and that answer doesn't work.

With this basic HTML:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="max-width: 200px">Short</td>
      <td style="width: auto">Long long long long long text</td>
      <td style="max-width: 200px">Short</td>
      <td style="max-width: 200px">Short</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would expect to see:

> Short (200px) | Long long long long long text (80% or so) | Short (200px) | Short (200px)

But instead I get four equal-sized columns.  I've also tried it without `table-layout: fixed`, and I've also tried adding `colgroup`/`col` tags, but nothing works.  I always wind up with the "short" columns stretching, instead of the long one.

So, I apologize for seemingly asking a duplicate question, but since none of the existing answers solve my example, I would appreciate any assistance I can get to create this basic "short, longgggg, short, short" column layout.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/melajalazu/edit?html,output - is that what you're after?  You can move the divider to see it resize.

Comment: width: auto will do nothing, it's the default value and max-width will only add a max boundary so it's like you did nothing. In most of the duplicates, there is the use of `width: 100%` and you are not using it

Comment: @KScandrett that was perfect.  Could you please put it in the form of an answer so I can accept it (well, if we can get this re-opened)?

Comment: @TemaniAfif `width: 100%` just makes that `<td>` take up all the width: I wind up with columns of `0 | 981 | 0 | 0`.  Even if I add `min-width: 200px;` to the other `<td>`s, they still wind up with 0 width.

Comment: Just in case this doesn't get re-opened (for anyone reading it after) the crux of @KScandrett's wonderful solution is that they used `width` style instead of a `max-width` and added `whitespace: nowrap` to each `<td>`.  I'm not sure why `width` limits the column width better than `max-width` (you'd expect the opposite to be true) ... but that's what works.  Thanks again @KScandrett; hopefully we can get this reopened so I can credit your helpful answer.

Comment: white-space: nowrap and width are also used in the duplicate (it's actually the first snippet in the first answer of the duplicate)